# Same content on many different Websites

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create a website and on every page I have a top nav bar. Acctualy I have 10 sites and when I have to change the content of the NavBar, I have to change it in every single site.

What is here best practice?

I have tryed to create a js file with the NavBar inside (document.write"".....), but with this solution I have to convert the html code into JS code and this is not my favorite solution?

Is there an better way?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: I think using `php` to do this and then using `readfile` or `include` is the easiest way to go about doing this. Or you can use the methods founds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003363/5648954) if you wish to stick with javascript

Comment: You've different websites or different pages of the same website?

Comment: I have different pages on the same website ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create a navbar.html file, contain the code of your nav bar, then

```
    <?php
         include 'navbar.html';
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can use media in css ,

> The @media rule is used in media queries to apply different styles for different media types/devices.

In my words, you can give different style based on screen's width.

The Second method is The Browser Object Model.
BOM,  screen.width can return you the width of the current browswer's width.

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not about applying styles for different screens